# How to visualize a spot light in Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, light

In my project I implemented a spot light using this [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Light-casters) and it works well. My problem is that I want to visualize the light itself bu I do not understand how to do it.

For example: I would like to achieve something like this

[image]

Any ideas or hints how such an effect can be achieved?

Comment: This is not light itself, it's volumetric light scattering effect. So-called "godrays" are related. It's based on using stencils and postprocessing, there were multiple publications on approach, e.g. in GPU Gems

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie ,  I found this [article](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-ii-light-and-shadows/chapter-13-volumetric-light-scattering-post-process) and as I understood I need to create separate fragment and vertex shaders and pass to them values from color and depth buffers of current rendered scene?  Sorry, I am new to computer graphics.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious: OpenGL doesn't have lights. It only has triangles and pixels (fragments). The light is not an object. The light on the ground is a special effect which is calculated by the ground shader when OpenGL draws the ground. If you also want to draw a cone with a different effect, then you have to draw a cone with a different shader which calculates that effect.

Comment: @user253751  just to clarify. So if I want to do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s60Drbt3x0E&t=1s) then I have to  draw a cone in order to simulate "beams" and then using [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-ii-light-and-shadows/chapter-13-volumetric-light-scattering-post-process)  algorithm (in cone fragment shader) assign color to each fragments of a cone? And projection on the plane can be achieved by spot light. Is it right?

Comment: @Einur Something like that, yeah. I didn't look through all the equations., but the pictures look like what you are trying to do. I also encourage you to try it yourself without the help of a book (unless you need it to be really accurate to real life). If you look at your example picture and think about it for a little bit, all you need to do is calculate the alpha based on the distance from the top of the cone.

Comment: By the way, you can also use a triangle instead of a cone, if the triangle always faces the camera.